# php unique values from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique

I am strugglin' with following array to retreive the unique values. This array comes from a nested product assembly structure. Tried several techniques but no result yet.
Maybe someone can help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_ID] => 1
            [amount] => 2.00
        )
```

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [product_ID] => 1
        [amount] => 2.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_ID] => 1
        [amount] => 2.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_ID] => 5
        [amount] => 6.00
    )
```

)

Goal is to retreive an array like:

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_ID] => 1
            [amount] => 2.00
        )`

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [product_ID] => 5
        [amount] => 6.00
    )
```

)

Comment: What if `product_ID => 1` has an amount of `3.00`? What to do with that?

Comment: @splash58: indeed. this is the solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest may be too extract the array indexing it by `product_ID` since indexes are unique:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'product_ID');
```

Comment: Awesome! Here's a slight modification in the event you want to reset the keys after removing the duplicates: array_values( array_column($array, null, 'product_ID') );